# Adding inner join to query making it 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a working query:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    COUNT() AS number_of_stuff
FROM 
    t2
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM t1
            WHERE content_id = t2.content_id)
GROUP BY 
    user_id
ORDER BY 
    number_of_stuff
```

Currently it returns `user_id` and counts of the number of times `user_id` is in t1.

I want to get `user_name` from t3 `where t2.user_id = t3.user_id`.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have described a simple `JOIN`:

```
select t2.user_id, t3.user_name, count(*) as number_of_stuff
from t2 join
     t3
     on t2.user_id = t3.user_id
where exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.content_id=t2.content_id)
group by t2.user_id, t3.user_name
order by number_of_stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
select user_name, user_id, count() as number_of_stuff 
from t2 inner join
t3 where t2.user_id = t3.user_id
where exists (select 1 from t1 where content_id=t2.content_id) 
group by user_name , user_id order by number_of_stuf
```